# How to get userid of newly registered user in Joomla 1.5.x?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I want to perform some operations on newly registered user when he hits the **register** button on register form and before he gets the system message about the activation mail(if useractivation setting is ON)

For that i have modified the file **components/com_user/controller.php**
In **register_save** method of the class **JController**, I have changed the original PHP code

```
if ( !$user->save() )
{
    JError::raiseWarning('', JText::_( $user->getError()));
    $this->register();
    return false;
}
```

into

```
if ( !$user->save() )
{
    JError::raiseWarning('', JText::_( $user->getError()));
    $this->register();
    return false;
}
include('custom_operations.php');
```

In **custom_operations.php** file, i have used **$user** variable to access username and email of newly registered user but following code gives me **0 value**

```
$user->get('id');
```

How can i access the userid of that newly registered user? Is there any other way to execute custom_operations.php file(I have also put an extra field in register form which is essential in this file)?
Please guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may create a joomla plugin with the type of user and be able to override the methods: onUserAfterSave and onUserBeforeSave methods. :)

Comment: I dont know much about joomla extensions development. Can u guide me about how to write a Joomla Plugin for above scenario?

Comment: try to visit this link http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin it will provide you a more detailed information about joomla plugins. ;)

Comment: Thank you. I created a plugin for that and in onUserAfterSave method, $user['id'] gave me the userid of newly registered user. :)

Answer (score 1):

If the user is registered successfully try below and see if it gives the value:

```
$user->id;
```

Else in the custom_operations.php file use **[mysql_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)**. It will give the id created by the last query. So just after the user registers, you can get the generated id in the table.